# Discord.py: Can't figure out how to use aiohttp in place of requests for this use case

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, discord.py, aiohttp

My original code (which made use of the `requests` library):

```
sess = requests.session()
req = sess.get(i) #i is a url
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
link = soup.find('a')['href']
with sess.get(link, stream=True) as req2:
    with open(os.path.join('C:\\save\\location', "download.txt"), "wb") as x_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(req2.raw, x_file)
```

What this code does:

1. Gets me the page at url `i`
2. Finds a particular download link `link` on said page (its a text file), using `bs4`.
3. The website uses session cookies, so I used `sessions` from `requests` to keep my cookies from one request to the next so it can download the file.
4. Writes the text file to my device at the mentioned directory using `shutil`.

As far as the working of the code is concerned, its OK. The file gets downloaded, and I have the required file named `download.txt` in the desired folder.

However the problem arises when I try to use it as part of a `discord.py` bot, in an `async` function. The code still does what it needs to do *but*: When it gets multiple commands, it executes them one after the other, which is obviously not desirable. I found from Stack Overflow itself that this is because using `requests` in an `async` function causes the whole code to block, resulting in what I observed. So instead of `requests`, I tried to use `aiohttp`, which apparently works well with `async` functions. I have managed to replace most of my usage of `requests` with `aiohttp`, and it does seem to be working well, however I cannot seem to figure out the correct syntax to do what I am doing above (downloading the text file while making use of session cookies, `bs4` and `shutil`.

How would I go about keeping my session cookies, using bs4 and writing the file to my device when using `aiohttp`?

**Edit**
The original link and file are of a personal nature, but in case you want a sample to test against, this should work in a similar way:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import shutil

sess = requests.session()
req = sess.get('https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2600')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
link = soup.find('a', text="EPUB (no images)")['href']
link="https://www.gutenberg.org"+link
with sess.get(link, stream=True) as req2:
    with open(os.path.join('C:\\save\\location', "war.epub"), "wb") as x_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(req2.raw, x_file)
```

This makes a file called `war.epub` in your desired directory, containing the epub version of War and Peace downloaded from the Gutenberg Project. How would I go about implementing this using aiohttp instead of requests?

Comment: Can you give a URL we can use for testing purposes? Or alternatively, what you are saving with `shutil`

Comment: @Benjin Ah, I can't really provide the url since its a kind of a personal website, but the specifics of what I'm saving are: it's a basic .txt file with a few characters inside it.

Comment: @Benjin actually, now I have found a public url where my code seems to work in a similar manner. Have updated the question. Maybe now you could have a look? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I have included `aiofile` to asynchronously write the file, as big files will cause the code to block.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from aiofile import AIOFile

async def write_file():
    sess = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    req = await sess.get('https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2600')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(await req.read(), 'html.parser')
    link = soup.find('a', text='EPUB (no images)')['href']
    link = 'https://www.gutenberg.org' + link

    req2 = await sess.get(link)

    async with AIOFile(os.path.join('C:\\save\\location', 'war.epub'), 'wb') as x_file:
        await x_file.write(await req2.read())

    await sess.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(write_file())
```

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiofile'`
:( Do I have to pip install something first? Oh and in case it matters, I'm using Python 3.8

Comment: Yes, you need to install `aiofile` using `pip`

Comment: Hi, I did that. But 1) on my device and python version, it says that the module is `aiofiles`, not `aiofile`, and gives this error now `ImportError: cannot import name 'AIOFile' from 'aiofiles'`

Comment: Which is weird, since I looked up aiofile online, and all examples do use `from aiofile import AIOFile`

Comment: When I used this as a separate script, it worked just fine, but when I used it as part of an on_message event for my discord.py bot, it gave a few errors:
`RuntimeError: This event loop is already running` for this: `loop.run_until_complete(write_file())`.

And then a couple more:
`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_message.<locals>.write_file' was never awaited
  pass
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: You don't need to use the last two lines of the script. That's just to show that the `async` function works on it's own.

Comment: I removed those, and just called the function normally. It still gave those errors, and didn't write the file to the directory. And when i didn't call the function, it didn't give the errors, but obviously didn't write the file to the directory either...I'm likely missing something really silly here.

Comment: Just to clarify, this bit of code is part of a larger on_message event.

Comment: Ah. I'm having a lot of mind farts today. Thanks again (and do forgive my slowness today)!