# Loop Doesn't Make My Command Work (Discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a problem where my loop seems to be blocking my other command from working.When I take out the loop my doddle command works,but when I put the loop back into the code,only the loop works,and not my doddle command.
(It gives me no errors and the loop is basically just to ping me on discord if someone is online in  minecraft.)

(The comments in the code are there on purpose)

```
def getinfo(call):
    req = requests.get(call)
    return req.json()
    # doddle command
       @bot.command()
       async def doddle(ctx):
            uuid = "uuid"
            apikey = 'api'
            url = f'https://api.hypixel.net/player?key={apikey}&uuid={uuid}'
            urldata = getinfo(url)
            playername3 = urldata["player"]["playername"]
            playerlogin3 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(urldata["player"]["lastLogin"]/1000)
            playerlogout3 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(urldata["player"]["lastLogout"]/1000)
            skillmining3 = urldata["player"]["achievements"]["skyblock_excavator"]
            skillforaging3 = urldata["player"]["achievements"]["skyblock_gatherer"]
            skillcombat3 = urldata["player"]["achievements"]["skyblock_combat"]
            # skillfishing3 = urldata["player"]['achievements']["skyblock_angler"]
            # skillenchanting3 = urldata["player"]['achievements']["skyblock_augmentation"]
            # skillalchemy3 = urldata["player"]['achievements']["skyblock_concoctor"]
            bedwarswins3 = urldata["player"]['achievements']["bedwars_wins"]
            bedwarsbeds3 = urldata["player"]['achievements']["bedwars_beds"]
            bedwarslevels3 = urldata["player"]['achievements']["bedwars_level"]
        
            infamousemb = discord.Embed(title='Info', discription='this is info about Infamous', colour=discord.Colour.orange())
            infamousemb.add_field(name='Player Name', value=playername3, inline=True)
            infamousemb.add_field(name='Login', value=playerlogin3.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), inline=True)
            infamousemb.add_field(name='Logout', value=playerlogout3.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), inline=False)
            infamousemb.add_field(name='Mining Skill', value=skillmining3, inline=True)
            infamousemb.add_field(name='Foraging Skill', value=skillforaging3, inline=True)
            infamousemb.add_field(name='Combat Skill', value=skillcombat3, inline=True)
            # infamousemb.add_field(name='Fishing Skill', value=skillfishing3, inline=True)
            # infamousemb.add_field(name='Alchemy Skill', value=skillalchemy3, inline=True)
            # infamousemb.add_field(name='Enchanting Skill', value=skillenchanting3, inline=True)
            infamousemb.add_field(name='Bed Wars Wins', value=bedwarswins3, inline=True)
            infamousemb.add_field(name='Bed Wars Beds', value=bedwarsbeds3, inline=True)
            infamousemb.add_field(name='Bed Wars Levels', value=bedwarslevels3, inline=True)
        
            await ctx.send(embed=infamousemb)
        # When I say redacted It'll show me redacted stats
        
        
        # the loop
        @tasks.loop(minutes=20, count=None)
        async def loop1():
            uuid = "uuid"
            apikey = 'api'
            url = f'https://api.hypixel.net/player?key={apikey}&uuid={uuid}'
            urldata = getinfo(url)
            playername4 = urldata["player"]["playername"]
            playerlogin4 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(urldata["player"]["lastLogin"]/1000)
            playerlogout4 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(urldata["player"]["lastLogout"]/1000)
            userid = '<@userid>'
            if playerlogin4 > playerlogout4:
                await dank.send(f'{playername4} Is Online {userid}')
            else:
                pass
        
        
        @bot.event
        async def on_message(self):
           if not loop1.is_running():
            loop1.start()
        
        
        TOKEN = "TOKEN"
        bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: What is `getinfo`? Without seeing the rest of the code, my best guess is something is blocking, causing your bot to freeze

Comment: Sorry about that I added in getinfo

Comment: The `requests` library is blocking and will freeze your bot. You need an `async` library that does the same thing, like `aiohttp`

Comment: @Benjin do you might have a idea how I can add aiohttp to my code?

Comment: Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63867626/discord-py-cant-figure-out-how-to-use-aiohttp-in-place-of-requests-for-this-us/63869872#63869872), just ignore the `aiofile` part

Comment: Benji I tried the thread you showed me, and I tried a couple of things,mostly changing variables,and I still cannot find out why it's not worrking,I keep getting "coroutine object is not scriptable"

Comment: You need to await a coroutine @Doddle

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I did but then I got another error that I can't seem to find anything about TypeError: '_RequestContextManager' object is not subscriptable